# Swift - Make Arrays Of Structs

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to add structs to an array. I know it's possible. I have seen it in another post on the site. But I am wondering if there is any way to add structs to an array without creating variables.

For example:

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var surname: String
    var phone: Int
    var isCustomer: Bool
}

var contacts: [Person] = []

var person1: Person = Person(name: "Jack", surname: "Johnson", phone: 2, isCustomer: false) 
var person2: Person = Person(name: "alex", surname: "a", phone: 3, isCustomer: false)

contacts.append(person1)
contacts.append(person2)

for contact in contacts {
    print("\(contact.name)")
}
```

In this code we use `person1` and `person2` to create a "contact". But if you have to create hundreds of contacts it is annoying to setup up all these variables.

What I tried is this:

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var surname: String
    var phone: Int
    var isCustomer: Bool
}

var contacts: [Person] = []

Person(name: "Jack", surname: "Johnson", phone: 2, isCustomer: false)

contacts.append(Person) // Here I get this error: "Cannot convert value of type '(Person).Type' (aka 'Person.Type') to expected argument type 'Person'
```

Is there any way to add structs to an array without creating variables?

Comment: Pull your data in from a database (ie Coredata, Realm, SQLite) a remote source (iCloud, Firebase) or even just a file (plist, csv).

Comment: Use a database or an array of dictionaries and a repeat loop.

Comment: How are either of these two comments useful?!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is giving you an error because you are trying to insert the type `Person` and not an instance. If you want to add a person to contacts without binding it to a variable just do this:

```
contacts.append(Person(name: "Jack", surname: "Johnson", phone: 2, isCustomer: false))
```

Comment: store the Person instance in a variable - and append the variable.

Comment: Do we any other methods?? b'coz i have more values in struct.

Comment: @iSrinivasan27, what do you mean by have more values in struct... If you have example code it would be helpful

Answer (score 5):

First, I think that as someone tell you, you should definitely use a database specially if you have a lot of data. Second, when you use `contacts.append(Person)`, it has no sense for swift's compiler.

One option is to use a loop and add a person to this array:

```
var contacts = [Person]() // take advantage of type inference
let names = ["Jack", "alex", ...] // ... means you can add as many names as you want
let surnames = ["Johnson", "a", ...]
let phones = [2, 3, ...]
let areCustomers = [false, false, ...]

for i in 0..<10 { // this will add 10 elements to contacts
    contacts.append(Person(name: names[i], surname: surname[i], phone: phones[i], isCustomer: areCustomers[i]))
}
```

In case you have a lot of data, I must insist you should consider using a database.